# Linux RDP with audio and mic

Tags: audio, freerdp

I've been trying to establish an RDP conexion with a Windows 7 machine from Linux with sound AND microphone redirection, I have tried rdesktop, remmina and freerdp with no use.

Finally, with freerdp I have finally managed to get sound and microphone redirection but from different sessions. I mean

`xfreerdp -u user -d domain -p password --plugin drdynvc --data audin -- server`

Allows me to send the microphone to the remote machine.

`xfreerdp -u user -d domain -p password --plugin rdpsnd --data pulse -- server`

Allows me to get the sound from the remote machine, but I can't manage to get both within the same session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. Looking for an answer for the remmina client, a guy had xfreerdp working and not remmina and he posted his xfreerdp command [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/remmina/mailman/message/31144481/). The thing was that when I was launching the command with the two plugins (drdynvc and rdpsnd) I was also passing two data strings audin and pulse and that doesn't work. The solutions is passing two plugins with just audin as data:

`xfreerdp -u user -d domain -p password --plugin drdynvc --plugin rdpsnd --data audin -- server`

Comment: This does not work for me on Arch Linux, I get an error about /usr/lib/freerdp/... not existing.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have been much improved in more recent versions of freerdp.

Now, just using the `/sound /microphone:sys:alsa` options seem to work fine.

Once https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/pull/3597 is merged, it'll be just `/sound /microphone` again.

https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/PreBuilds contains nightly builds which worked much better than my distribution's outdated packages.

Comment: Is there any released version where this works, or do I still need a nightly build?

Comment: I'm using this, and sound works, but microphone does not.  See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372995/xfreerdp-microphone-forwarding-but-windows-says-no-audio-devices-are-installed).